# Best way to store data between two request

Tags: wcf

I need one a bit theoretical advice. Here is my situation : I have a search system, which returns a list of found items. But the user is allowed to display only particular amount of items on one page, so when his **first request** is sent to my WCF service, it gets the whole list, then tests if the list isn't longer then the ammount of items my user is allowed to get and if the list isn't longer, there is no problem and my service returns the whole list, but when it is, then there is problem. I need to let the user choose which page he wants to display, so I let the javascript know that the user should choose page and the "page number dialog" is shown and then user is sending the **second request** with page number. And based on this request the webservice selects relewant items and sends them back to user. So what I need to do is to store the whole list on the server between **first** and **second** request and I 'd appreciate any idehow to store it. I was thinking about session, but I don't know if it is possible to set timeout only to particular sesion (ex. `Session["list"]`), because the list is used only once and can have thousands of items, so I don't want to keep it on the server to long.

PS. I Can't use standart pagination, the scenario has to be exactly how is described above.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a classic use-case for memcached.  It is a network based key-value store for storing temporary values.  Unlike in-memory state, it can be used to share temporary cached values among servers (say you have multiple nodes), and it is a great way to save state across requests (avoiding the latency that would be caused by using cookies, which are transmitted to/from the server on each http request).

The basic approach is to create a unique ID for each request, and associate it with a particular (set of) memcached key for that user's requests.  You then save this unique ID in a cookie (or similar mechanism).

A warning, though, the memory is volatile, so can be lost at any point.  In practice, this is not frequent, and the memcached algorithm uses a LRU queue.  More details http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/NewOverview

http://memcached.org/

> Memcached is an in-memory key-value store for small chunks of arbitrary data (strings, objects) from results of database calls, API calls, or page rendering.

I'm not a .net programmer, but there appear to be implementations:

http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/Clients

> .Net memcached client
>
> https://sourceforge.net/projects/memcacheddotnet .Net 2.0 memcached
>   client
>
> http://www.codeplex.com/EnyimMemcached Client developed in .NET 2.0
>   keeping performance and extensibility in mind. (Supports consistent
>   hashing.) http://www.codeplex.com/memcachedproviders BeIT Memcached
>   Client (optimized C# 2.0)
>
> http://code.google.com/p/beitmemcached jehiah
>
> http://jehiah.cz/projects/memcached-win32

Comment: Sounds like a great answer, but can you elaborate? Perhaps explain why memcached will help, how the basic setup works, add a link or two for more in depth info?